# Html code in javascript not working using document.write

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I have tried this code only in html and it is working but when using document.write  it is not executing at all.
notepad++ is shading that code black till img tag(including img).
I am new and i cant identify error in it.

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
document.write("
<table valign="middle" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="15%" >
    <tr align="center" valign="middle" height="50%" >
        <td><img src="images/logo.png" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="10%">
        <td colspan=2>
            <input type="text" id="eno" maxlength="9" size="9" placeholder="Enrollment No." style="border:0;font-size:72;width:100%;height:100%;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="10%">
        <td colspan=2>
            <input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="SaveEno()" style="font-size:72;color:white;background-color:black;width:100%;height:100%;border:0;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
");
</script>
```

Comment: When using `document.write("` you either need to escape all following " (e.g.: \") or use single quotes ('). Then it will be OK.

Comment: You also have unescaped line breaks in the string to be written to the document, causing JavaScript to generate syntax errors. If you prefix your code with `use strict`; and turn on the browser console, you are going to see what's going on.

Comment: If you can post a question on Stackoverflow with a trick to bypass duplicate question, then you can definitely solve your question by yourself. Try that.

Comment: The JavaScript is invalid because the double quotes `"` in the HTML fragment are ending the string and breaking everything. You should really use a [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) using backticks `

Comment: always downvotes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double quotes in the HTML fragment are interfering with the JavaScript. You should really be using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) unless you need to support Internet Explorer. If so you'll either have to use single quotes around the HTML fragment or escape all the double quotes in it `\"`.

```js
document.write(`
    <table valign="middle" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="15%" >
        <tr align="center" valign="middle" height="50%" >
            <td><img src="images/logo.png" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="10%">
            <td colspan=2>
                <input type="text" id="eno" maxlength="9" size="9" placeholder="Enrollment No." style="border:0;font-size:72;width:100%;height:100%;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="10%">
            <td colspan=2>
                <input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="SaveEno()" style="font-size:72;color:white;background-color:black;width:100%;height:100%;border:0;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    `);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case document.write("") takes into consideration the formatting of tags like new line characters, double quotes etc. As it is not a javascript string do not use double quotes. For this to work have all the tags inside ``` document.write(``) ``` function. For more https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp